# “FATAL: could not read from the boot medium! system halted”

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, centos, openfiler

I've a problem with Virtual Box, I cannot access to a CentOS virtual machine. I'm using a openfiler local server connected to my network.In addition, I can access to all the other LUN disks that I've created there. and before moving out from my old home I had perfect access to this virtual machine. On virtualBox configuration the storage seems to be ok. I've already tried reseting my computer checking for user permissions to use virtual box machines, reinstalling virtualbox manager, but nothing. Any idea of how to overcome this problem would be greatly appreciated.

My VIrtualBox version is 4.0.12 r72916
My mapping information

```
LUN Id.     LUN Path    R/W Mode    SCSI Serial No.     SCSI Id.    Transfer Mode
16  /dev/vgdata1/dbmobiltux     write-thru  lBuLXb-XXqz-Ejlv    lBuLXb-XXqz-Ejlv    blockio 


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.
** If you make changes to this file while any VirtualBox related application
** is running, your changes will be overwritten later, without taking effect.
** Use VBoxManage or the VirtualBox Manager GUI to make changes.
-->
<VirtualBox xmlns="http://www.innotek.de/VirtualBox-settings" version="1.11-linux">
  <Machine uuid="{0076f586-129a-4279-aeee-e894fad87b8b}" name="dbmobiltux" OSType="RedHat_64" snapshotFolder="Snapshots" lastStateChange="2012-03-12T16:31:33Z">
    <MediaRegistry>
      <HardDisks>
        <HardDisk uuid="{b2f18f58-4156-4f93-8434-2d8725e85b33}" location="192.168.2.20|iqn.openfiler.storage.soltux.com|16" format="iSCSI" type="Normal">
          <Property name="LUN" value="16"/>
          <Property name="TargetAddress" value="192.168.2.20"/>
          <Property name="TargetName" value="iqn.openfiler.storage.soltux.com"/>
        </HardDisk>
      </HardDisks>
      <DVDImages/>
      <FloppyImages/>
    </MediaRegistry>
    <ExtraData>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastCloseAction" value="powerOff"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastGuestSizeHint" value="720,400"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastNormalWindowPosition" value="397,154,720,445"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/MiniToolBarAlignment" value="bottom"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/SaveMountedAtRuntime" value="yes"/>
      <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/ShowMiniToolBar" value="yes"/>
    </ExtraData>
    <Hardware version="2">
      <CPU count="1" hotplug="false">
        <HardwareVirtEx enabled="true" exclusive="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExNestedPaging enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExVPID enabled="true"/>
        <PAE enabled="true"/>
        <HardwareVirtExLargePages enabled="false"/>
        <HardwareVirtForce enabled="false"/>
      </CPU>
      <Memory RAMSize="768" PageFusion="false"/>
      <HID Pointing="PS2Mouse" Keyboard="PS2Keyboard"/>
      <HPET enabled="false"/>
      <Chipset type="PIIX3"/>
      <Boot>
        <Order position="1" device="HardDisk"/>
        <Order position="2" device="DVD"/>
        <Order position="3" device="None"/>
        <Order position="4" device="None"/>
      </Boot>
      <Display VRAMSize="12" monitorCount="1" accelerate3D="false" accelerate2DVideo="false"/>
      <RemoteDisplay enabled="false" authType="Null" authTimeout="5000"/>
      <BIOS>
        <ACPI enabled="true"/>
        <IOAPIC enabled="true"/>
        <Logo fadeIn="true" fadeOut="true" displayTime="0"/>
        <BootMenu mode="MessageAndMenu"/>
        <TimeOffset value="0"/>
        <PXEDebug enabled="false"/>
      </BIOS>
      <USBController enabled="true" enabledEhci="true"/>
      <Network>
        <Adapter slot="0" enabled="true" MACAddress="080027F412C6" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <NAT>
            <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
            <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
          </NAT>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="1" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800274DFA86" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="2" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027F781F3" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="3" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800276E1619" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="4" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800271C2705" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="5" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027323A90" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="6" enabled="false" MACAddress="080027DCD583" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
        <Adapter slot="7" enabled="false" MACAddress="0800279980DB" cable="true" speed="0" type="82540EM">
          <DisabledModes>
            <NAT>
              <DNS pass-domain="true" use-proxy="false" use-host-resolver="false"/>
              <Alias logging="false" proxy-only="false" use-same-ports="false"/>
            </NAT>
          </DisabledModes>
        </Adapter>
      </Network>
      <UART>
        <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x3f8" IRQ="4" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
        <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x2f8" IRQ="3" hostMode="Disconnected"/>
      </UART>
      <LPT>
        <Port slot="0" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="4"/>
        <Port slot="1" enabled="false" IOBase="0x378" IRQ="4"/>
      </LPT>
      <AudioAdapter controller="AC97" driver="Pulse" enabled="true"/>
      <RTC localOrUTC="UTC"/>
      <SharedFolders/>
      <Clipboard mode="Bidirectional"/>
      <IO>
        <IoCache enabled="true" size="5"/>
        <BandwidthGroups/>
      </IO>
      <Guest memoryBalloonSize="0"/>
      <GuestProperties/>
    </Hardware>
    <StorageControllers>
      <StorageController name="Controlador IDE" type="PIIX4" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="true" Bootable="true">
        <AttachedDevice passthrough="false" type="DVD" port="1" device="0">
          <HostDrive src="/dev/sr0"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
      <StorageController name="Controlador SATA" type="AHCI" PortCount="2" useHostIOCache="false" Bootable="true" IDE0MasterEmulationPort="0" IDE0SlaveEmulationPort="1" IDE1MasterEmulationPort="2" IDE1SlaveEmulationPort="3">
        <AttachedDevice type="HardDisk" port="1" device="0">
          <Image uuid="{b2f18f58-4156-4f93-8434-2d8725e85b33}"/>
        </AttachedDevice>
      </StorageController>
    </StorageControllers>
  </Machine>
</VirtualBox>
```

the log files:
http://pastebin.com/SNA7usJj

Comment: So did you create some iSCSI targets on the Openfiler server, and you have been using those with your virtual machines? Could you also include the version of VirtualBox and the relevant machine XML config file and the log files too? Maybe put them on pastebin?

Comment: Information Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 844 of your log file is the most helpful:

```
00:00:03.413 Guest Log: Could not read from the boot medium! System halted.
```

Looking back up, starting at line 709 you can see that VirtualBox is able to talk iSCSI to your exported LUN, so I don't think it is a networking problem. I would suggest trying to attach this drive to a working VM that you can run fsck on and check the boot records. My guess is that something has become corrupted with that storage device.

If you have a backup you could also try to compare/copy the boot information from the good drive to the bad.

Comment: I'll try this when I arrive home... I'll run fsck and check for errors.

Comment: My disk is dead!! it's recognised as it where virgin!! I had to re-install this lun, luckily I have a recent backup

Comment: the think get really strange with the FSCK it seems to be a virgin disk,so I finished re-installing everything there.Luckily, I had a backup of everything on that lun!! I should made as you said from the beginning, so I would save a lot of time,